# Calculate a duration using excel

Tags: excel

I'm working with a column that has a duration in the format hh:mm:ss. How can I calculate the number of minutes, with a minimum of one? So `00:00:30 = 1` , `00:01:20 = 2` and so on?

Comment: So you want to round up to the nearest minute?

Comment: Yes but I want a number of minutes, not the time format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time is a decimal portion of the day, use this:

```
=ROUNDUP(A1*60*24,0)
```

[image]